Net Maui Notification with plugin.firebase
I'm developing an App with the Plugin.Firebase that involves receiving notifications with data passed in the data fields, for example:
var message = new Message()
{
    Notification = new Notification()
    {
        Title = "My Title",
        Body = "My Body"
    },
    Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"Type",XXX},    
        {"A",XXX},
    },
    Topic = "XXXX"
};

Based on the App's Default language, the Body will contain Field A instead of the original Body ("My Body").
All this works correctly if the App is in the foreground, if it is in stand-by or is not in memory, the Original Body is always shown.
The FirebaseMessagingService OnMessageReceived Event appears not to be invoked.
Is it possible?
There is a different approach to managing background notifications?

This is the expected behavior: when the user is not actively using your app, the system will show the notification. If you don't want that behavior, send messages without a notification property - so-called data-only messages.
Also see the Firebase documentation on message types, which explains this distinction too.
